# Google Cloud | Compute Engine | VM Stuck

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am having 20+ VMs using google compute engine, and only one in particular is getting stuck. By getting stuck i mean, i cannot call virtual KVM from google console, getting SSH error. When i try to SSH to the VM from outside, it is crashing with "reset by peer".

Basicly all actions i can take, is to reset the VM and everything get back online. Did not managed to find a way to escalate the issue since i am with "Bronze" support package, which is absurd since i really believe it is hardware issue.

Offtopic:
The VM is using debian 9 in mariad db in production enviroment, and i am using same config on another VM which is runing for like half of year. Both VMs were created nearly the same time, and this issue started to occur from like two weeks ago. Both VMs are having same spec hardware, and the one getting stuck, is having like 1000 queries per 24 hours max !

Will be really thankfull if somebody can point me out how to escalate/move forward my issue.

Regards,

Comment: have you opened a support case with your bronze package?

Answer (score 2):

In case it could be useful to somebody, the reason it frequently happened to me was because we were reaching the memory limit (RAM).

Temporary solution was to stop and restart the machine, flushing every unnecessary memory leaking processes.

The final solution was to improve Redis settings (after we discovered it was the cause of it) to have a maxmemory setting.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons this could happen. This [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) describe some tips to troubleshoot and resolve common SSH issues. You can debug the issue using the serial console and try to find any error messages in the serial console log. This is particularly useful when you cannot log in with SSH or if the instance has no connection to the network.

To know how to enable interactive access and connect to an instance's serial console, read [Interacting with the Serial Console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console).

Comment: I feel this is not the issue @axelkeegan facing

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. Testing the proposal of the user, if works will close the issue.

[Google cloud compute engine freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47470181/google-cloud-compute-engine-freeze)