# Google Cloud compute engine randomly becomes unaccessable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, linux-kernel, debian, google-compute-engine

I have a problem with a custom (1 vCPU, 2 GB memory) compute instance running Apache and 3 python scripts which essentially waits for messages and runs some SQL queries and creates reports. Once in a while, the entire instance becomes unresponsive for Apache, SSH and even access to the serial console. It looks like the entire instance is frozen. The only solution for this is to actively log in to my Google Cloud account and restart the instance.

I have checked the disk space because Google suggested in one of their pages that it might lead to the instance freezing but I still have 6GB available disk space so it shouldn't be an issue.

I have added logs from "Serial port 1 (console)" in case it might help with diagnosing the issue.

Could someone please assist me with finding out why this is happening? Thank you in advance.

Serial console logs output:

https://pastebin.com/raw/Z9gADmCn

```
Nov 18 19:14:24 web-server systemd[1]: Stopping System Logging Service...

Nov 18 19:14:24 web-server systemd[1]: Stopped System Logging Service.

Nov 18 19:14:24 web-server systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...

Nov 18 19:14:24 web-server systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.

Nov 18 19:14:25 web-server dhclient[558]: bound to 10.166.0.10 -- renewal in 1434 seconds.

Nov 18 19:14:25 web-server ifup[516]: bound to 10.166.0.10 -- renewal in 1434 seconds.
```

Comment: Howdy and welcome to Stackoverflow.   What I'd suggest is to add in the Stackdriver agents for both logging and monitoring into your VM.  Next time the hang occurs, pour through the Stackdriver Logging and examine the history of your machine through Stackdriver metrics.  Look for possible resource outages such as memory or file handles or network connections.  Stackdriver is your friend for analysis.  The console logs contain the bootup start info but not a great deal more (opinion).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I have added it. It seems like I already had some type of logging activated on my instance already. From what I can tell they're not problematic. Maybe you can see something?

https://prnt.sc/pyqxyk
https://prnt.sc/pyqy7g
https://prnt.sc/pyqyf9

Comment: These logs look ok ... but think of yourself like a doctor.  If the patient is sick and you run a test (look at one set of logs) and they don't show anything, you keep on going.  I'm thinking memory usage and CPU usage might be next.  If a machine just "gives up" experience points me to it being out of some resource.  How long does your solution run for before it hangs?  I am sniffing for a resource leak that eventually exhausts the machine.  A memory leak would manifest as a growing utilization of memory.

Comment: That's a great analogy! Since I didn't log until now I'm not sure how long it went between each restart, but it wouldn't be a stretch to say once every week. I checked the memory utilization and there seems that there **might** be a slow memory leak (Growing from 18% to 21% in an hour), I'll check again tomorrow if it's actually growing. I'll let you know what happens, thank you!

Pic: https://prnt.sc/pyrrmz

Answer (score 0):

This question should better be asked on Serverfault to get attention from Sysadmins instead of Devs here.

Before you use the suggestion above in Kolban's comment, i'd recommend checking some simple things.

1- Check if instance was under maintenance (in instance details page you can find your maintenance window)

2- Also under instance details page, you should be able to check CPU and Memory utilization and see if there was a spike at the time of the freeze. That should put you in the right direction.

3- Check system/apps logs: I'd recommend checking /var/log/syslog and if applicable /var/log/nginx/error.log for example.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm afraid I could not find the maintenance window you were talking about.  I have enabled Stackdriver and an uptime check so I can get long term statistics about the machine and get relevant syslog entries next time it happens.

When I stumble upon this again (with better data), would it be better if I created a thread in Sysadmins and let this thread be left alone?

Comment: Supporting what Notauser have said, you might need to check whether there is any [hosterror](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#hosterror) is logged on operation log of the VM.Configuring [live migration](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/live-migration), might help to avoid downtime in some host system events such as a software or hardware update.

Comment: I would also like to refer you to [these](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps) [articles](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/robustsystems), that explains how to build 'resilient applications' and 'robust systems' to avoid such situations when your virtual machine (VM) instances suffer an unexpected failure/downtime.

Comment: What I meant by Sysadmins vs Devs is System Administrators vs Developers
. See more info here[1] 
[1] https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2602/when-to-post-on-serverfault-vs-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in one of my google compute engine instance where it was  becoming freeze after some time from starting .
When i resetting the instance ,then again it started working fine .
So the issue i found was of less CPU/RAM on the instance and the processes on that instance require more CPU/RAM .So when in changed the CPU/RAM from 1CPU/3.75 GB RAM to 4 CPU/16 GB RAM it started working fine permanently.

On the core of this issue,the machine was created from disk snapshot in which different application like tomcat,postgres was configured for high CPU/Memory etc .So it look like when the machine become fully operational then it faced less memory for required processes which lead to slowness and freeze in the instance .

Answer (score 0):

I cannot put comments, so I reply here. This symptom has existed for a long time, which is likely caused by that the GCP compute engine lacks of swap file.

I resolved it by creating a swap file described in this article: [Google cloud compute engine freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47470181/google-cloud-compute-engine-freeze).